# can composite primary key be referenced as a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID,LastName)
);
```

I want to add a foreign key to the following table

```
create table License(
  LicenseID int not null,
  PersonID int not null,
  issue_date date,
  primary key (LicenseID)
);
```

how should I reference it ?!

Comment: So did you try and add the foreign key

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes `mysql> alter table License add foreign key (PersonId) references Persons(ID,LastName);`                                            
`ERROR 1239 (42000): Incorrect foreign key definition for 'foreign key without name': Key reference and table reference don't match`                                                                     and                                                                                                                             `mysql> alter table License add foreign key (PersonId) references Persons(PK_Person);`               this gives error

Answer (score 0):

Any foreign key must have columns to match *all* the columns of the primary key it references.

If your parent table has a compound primary key with two columns, an int and a varchar, then the foreign key that references it must also have two columns, an int and a varchar, in the same order.